# R: Scraping aspx with content from doPostBack script

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

**UPDATE 2**

***Since I made some advance, I opened a new, more precise question:***
[R: scraping data after POST only works for first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068532/r-scraping-data-after-post-only-works-for-first-page)

**My plan:**

I would like to scrape drug informations offered by the Swiss government for an University research project from:

http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?searchType=Substance&searchValue=

The page does offer a robotx.txt file, however, it's content is freely available to the public and I assume that scraping this data is unprohibited.

**What I've already achieved:**

I could manage to scrape the html table of the first search page:

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr)")

url<-"http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?searchType=Substance&searchValue="

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="ctl00_cphContent_gvwPreparations"]') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  tibble()
```

Now I would like to scrape the details of the listed drugs (which appears at the page bottom if I click on the link in the Präparat=preparation column).
However, this link is not a simple hmtl, it is a doPostBack javascript.

I figured out that these scripts follow this rule:

> javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$gvwPreparations$ctl02$ctl00','')
>   javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$gvwPreparations$ctl03$ctl00','')
>   ...
>   javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$gvwPreparations$ctl16$ctl00','')

so

> gvw$Preparations$.. = gvw$Preparations$ctl(Nr in the List +1)$ct100

**Where I fail:**

I tried to implement this solution to ge the detailed drug information:

[Scrape website with R by navigating doPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574742/scrape-website-with-r-by-navigating-dopostback?rq=1)

however,

```
url<-"http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?searchType=Substance&searchValue="

pgsession<-html_session(url)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
page<-rvest:::request_POST(pgsession,"http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?searchType=Substance&searchValue=",
                           body=list(
                             `__VIEWSTATE`=pgform$fields$`__VIEWSTATE`$value,
                             `__EVENTTARGET`="ctl00$cphContent$gvwPreparations$ctl02$ctl00",
                             `__EVENTARGUMENT`="",
                             `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`=pgform$fields$`__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`$value,
                             `__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED`=pgform$fields$`__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED`$value,
                             `__EVENTVALIDATION`=pgform$fields$`__EVENTVALIDATION`$value
                           ),
                           encode="form"
)


read_html(page) %>% html_nodes(css="ctl00_cphContent_fvwPreparation")
```

gives me `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

I assume that my `request_POST` is not correct...
However, I could not figure out what's wrong.

**So the open points are:**

- What is the correct way to get the detailed information of the
  doPostBack java scripts (i.e. the table that appears at the end of the page if one clicks on the link in the first column)
- How can I get the results of the other pages (935)? Do I have to use
  `RSelenium` and click through the results, if yes, how can the `RSelenium` and `rvest` approach be combined? Or is there an easier way
  to do so?

**UPDATE**

I could solve the first point (at least partially) with this help from *hrbrmstr*:

https://www.queryxchange.com/q/27_51801321/getting-xml-nodeset-0-when-using-html-nodes-from-rvest-package-in-r/

```
read_html(page) %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_cphContent_fvwPreparation"]') %>% html_text
```

which gives me the detailed information (in a bit an unstructured form).

however, I still do not know, how to get the info from all other pages.

With RSelenium I would do something like:

```
library("RSelenium")

# star selenum
sel <- remoteDr(browserName = "chrome", port = 4445L)

# go to the URL 
sel %>% 
  go("http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?searchType=Substance&searchValue=")


# chose max page
sel %>% 
  findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = '100']") %>%  # find the submit button 
  elementClick()  # click it
```

However, I do not know how to combine `RSelenium` and `rvest`

Is it possible to select the maximum of displayed pages with the URL, something like

```
http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?PageSize=500
```

And then chose the next page with

```
http://www.spezialitaetenliste.ch/ShowPreparations.aspx?PageSize=500&PageNr=2
```

**UPDATE 2**

***Since I made some advance, I opened a new, more precise question:***
[R: scraping data after POST only works for first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068532/r-scraping-data-after-post-only-works-for-first-page)